# not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, function

I keep getting this error **'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'** how do i fix it

```
def is_valid_ip_address(numberlist):
    y = (list(numberlist.split(".")))
    z = len(y)

    if y[0] > 0 and y[0] < 255 and z < 4 and y[1] > 0 and y[1] < 255 and z < 4 and y[2] > 0 and y[2] < 255 and z < 4 and y[3] > 0 and y[3] < 255 and z < 4 and y[4] > 0 and y[4] < 255 and z < 4:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

is_valid_ip_address("500.3.55.3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parsing of the IP address is incorrect. It leaves the parts of the ip address as strings, not ints. And you can't compare strings to ints.

Try this:

```
def is_valid_ip_address(numberlist):
    y = list(map(int, numberlist.split(".")))
    z = len(y)

    if y[0] > 0 and y[0] < 255 and z < 4 and y[1] > 0 and y[1] < 255 and z < 4 and y[2] > 0 and y[2] < 255 and z < 4 and y[3] > 0 and y[3] < 255 and z < 4 and y[4] > 0 and y[4] < 255 and z < 4:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

is_valid_ip_address("500.3.55.3")
```

Output:

```
false
```